# Best practice for using ASPNETDB in combination with another database

Tags: asp.net, membership

Need to add users/roles etc to my web application.  I want to use aspnetdb, because other web applications will need the same thing.  I do not want to merge these tables into my db, either for the same reason.  But, in my database I have tables that store information related to the user that I want to access.

e.g.

MealTable
Id,
UserId,
MealName,
Calories

So what's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is the way you seems that you use it.

Use the **UserId** to connect your users in your application with the aspnetdb that keep the users.

Now if you like to keep yours application robust when you go to delete a user, you need to search all your other database application to see if this is possible/permited.